# How can I show JavaScript and other code on my webpage, so that it can be copied?

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

Here on Stack Overflow, when we type in code in a specific format it will display it as code with syntax highlighting.  I want to be able to do this on my website, however, I want to use the format that is on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.oncontextmenu)!

I have seen this style of displaying code on many websites, but have been unable to figure out how they do it, and specifically how they allow 'view plain' and 'print' options.

I am assuming there is a plugin that I can use, but am lost as to where to find it.

Comment: are you using any CMS for your website. or its plain website without any CMS. if u r using wordpress u can try this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/

else you can use jquery syntax highlighter .
http://steamdev.com/snippet/

Comment: No CMS. Just a plain ol' custom site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's called [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/). Depending on your website's framework (is it a blog?) you can find several solutions to suit your needs. There are numerous plugins for [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=syntax%20highlighter) that utilise SyntaxHighlighter, for instance. I was in the same situation a year ago and decided to make my own called [Crayon](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/). Note that Crayon doesn't use SyntaxHighlighter, I built it from scratch, and that it uses server-side highlighting through PHP and uses JavaScript only for interactivity. SyntaxHighlighter uses only JavaScript and is client-side highlighting.

Comment: Yeah it's SyntaxHighlighter for sure, I just need to learn how to use it right, haha.